# when i make the input channel decrease to half of it in 1D conv,is this being a kind of channel reduction or some how bottleneck?

Tags: pytorch, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, stack-overflow

Suppose I have two tensors with shape : `b*c*1*1` then i concatenate them up to `b*2c*1*1`. Now I want to add a 1D conv so the output shape is : `b*c*1*1`，by using below self.conv1 to achieve this.

```
self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(1, 1, kernel_size=k,stride=2,padding=int((k-2)/2) ,bias=False)

def forward(self, x):
       x = self.conv1(x.squeeze(-1).transpose(-1, -2)).transpose(-1, -2).unsqueeze(-1)
```

Is this a kind of channel reduction or some bottleneck?
note that this operation is actually equal to the operation of a 2D conv on b*c*2*1，i guess.

Thank you for solving my question.